# How to find asp:Login LoginError error type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

When the `LoginError` event fires for the `asp:Login` control, how can I find why the error happened?

Is there something like an `e.ErrorType` property that tells me why the login was unsuccessful? Or do I have to check everything manually like in this tutorials:

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs or http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/howto-errors-login-asp4-csharp.aspx

Comment: There is no "Out-of-the-box" error type information as far as I've seen in the past for the `LoginError` event (although I agree with you that it would be ***really*** nice).  In fact, in my experience the `EventArgs` parameter is always `null` for me for that event in the `asp:Login` control =/.  But, I think you've found some really good resources in those links!

Comment: (I was going to put that as an answer, but it didn't feel right to do so, since I'm essentially just saying, "No")

Comment: @jadarnel27: hehe, it's not an answer, but if nobody finds something more useful than those links I'd give you +1

Comment: Haha, thanks!  I posted it, but also upvoted your question, because I'm really curious to see if someone else knows (I never thought to ask this, always just blindly accepted the inconvenience!).

Comment: @jadarnel27: I'm surprised that nobody asked this before ;) Anyway, here you go +1

Comment: It is really embarrassing. I found under the situation like existing code already been implimented for login using membership. Now licensing part I am doing. Where I unable to predict, newly created user not authenticating. Since no earlier developer to guide what exactly built :(

Answer (score 4):

There is no "Out-of-the-box" error type information as far as I've seen in the past for the `LoginError` event (although I agree with you that it would be ***really*** nice).  In fact, in my experience the `EventArgs` parameter is always `null` for me for that event in the `asp:Login` control =/

It's **quite** possible that someone else is aware of something I'm not, but I think we are all stuck manually determining why the `LoginError` occurred for now.

Comment: I could give you the answer for this question since nobody is likely to answer it anymore...is it ok?

Comment: @Mentoliptus The other option would be to [put a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) on the question so that it gets some more attention.  Only select my answer if you feel it answered your question =)  I'm not worried about the rep.

Comment: But I'm worried that it'll never get answered...because it has no answer ;)

Comment: @Mentoliptus Haha, indeed. Unfortunately this is probably as good as it gets =)